# Codeigniter Cache Driver 500 error on load

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, driver

I want to use the CI cache driver but when I use `$this->load->driver('cache');` in MY_Controller.php or a normal controller I get a server error page (500 error).

I am using CI 2.1.3

Any idea in how to fix it? What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, apparently you need to load it `$this->load->library('cache');` even though its a driver.

EDIT// Never mind it was all a mess because of a CI error, I am using the 3.0 Driver model now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error logs.

Probably means your cache directory doesn't have sufficient permissions!

Comment: I did check that, only debug messages are showing up, no error or mention of not writable cache folder.

Comment: Can you post the debug messages and your apache error log entries? Internal server error mostly means there are errors but they aren't being displayed.

Comment: I am running it locally, all the debugs are just initialized messages, and the logs folder is empty.